# Pexpect doesn't run the command, only prints it on the screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, pexpect, qsub

So I'm trying to use pexpect for running qsub, but I'm running simple command like 'ls' to see if it works first. The problem here though is that pexpect prints the command on the terminal but doesn't actually run it. Can anyone please take a look at it and tell me if I'm misunderstanding how Pexpect works?

Here is the pexpect module:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import sys
import pexpect
fout = open('pythontest', 'w')
process = pexpect.spawnu('qsub -I -l nodes=1:ppn=2', logfile=fout, 
echo=True)
process.expect('ready')
process.sendline('pwd')
process.expect('')
process.sendline('exit')
process.close()
```

And the output file:

```
qsub: waiting for job 23315.as0.al-salam.loc to start`
qsub: job 23315.as0.al-salam.loc ready`

pwd
exit
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You will get help much quicker, if you formulate your question including a [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In other words, please put your code here so that we can try to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Which version of python do you use?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.5.1

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this entirely, because I don't have `qsub` on my machine, but logging into another machine with `ssh`, I get the same behaviour with your code. If I alter the code in the following way, the result of `pwd` is found in the logfile as expected:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import sys
import pexpect
fout = open('pythontest', 'w')
##process = pexpect.spawnu('qsub -I -l nodes=1:ppn=2', logfile=fout, echo=True)
process = pexpect.spawnu('ssh user@server', logfile=fout, echo=True)
#process.expect('ready')
process.expect('>')
process.sendline('pwd')
#process.expect('')
process.expect('>')
process.sendline('exit')
process.close()
```

The `>` is the last character of my bash prompt.

**EDIT**:

Using `qsub` interactively on our supercomputer (where we unfortunately only have python 2.6), I also get a bash prompt (which for me ends on `>`). So maybe run `qsub` interactively once without `pexpect` to see what you actually get from your shell and edit your script accordingly.

Comment: well, when I run qsub by hand the bash prompt doesn't give me anyhting except for "as0$" (as0 is the name of the machine. So I don't really know what character to run as expect. I tried with "\r\n" as posted in the Pexpect documentation but still the same result: doesn't run the command.

Comment: @SirajusSalekin what about `$`?

Comment: Using '$' doesn't work either (which I tested), and they also noted that in the documentation (they advised to use "\r\n" instead)

Comment: @SirajusSalekin ok, then I'm afraid I cannot help you.

Comment: Thank you, though. I appreciate you for the effort!

Comment: @SirajusSalekin just another try: did you notice that after `process.sendline('pwd')` I wait for the bash prompt (`process.expect('>')`), while you wait for an empty string (`process.expect('')`)? Waiting for an empty string means basically not to wait at all, so `pexpect` may just exit before it has time to log the output of `pwd`...